# Dry milk substitutions?

Tags: baking, substitutions

I'm trying to make homemade Tootsie rolls, and the recipe calls for 1 1/4 cup of instant non-fat dry milk powder, which I don't have. Is there any way I can substitute regular milk for this? If so, do I use the same amount?

Comment: Does the recipe contain water or another liquid?

Comment: The entire recipe would be useful here. Not just whether liquid is included, but what kind of candy it is and how its made. The procedure determines how important the inclusion of liquid is in a candy recipe.

Comment: The rest of the ingredients are 1/2 cup honey, 6 tbsp unsweetened cocoa powder, 1 tsp vanilla extract,  1 tbsp unsalted melted butter, 1/4 cup powdered sugar,  and 1 pinch salt.                    The recipe says to combine the honey, cocoa powder, and vanilla in a large bowl, then add in the melted butter and mix well. Add in the sugar and salt, mix well. Mix in powdered mil 1/4 cup at a time until dough forms. When no longer able to stir it with a spoon, use your hands to knead the it.

Comment: Keep adding mild powder until dough forms. The finished dough should be firm and a little sticky. Roll into a ball and place on waxed paper lightly sprayed with cooking oil. Let it rest for 5-10 minutes. Cut dough into 3/4 in by 2 in lengths. Then wrap and store in the refrigerator.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try whey powder, which you can find in the sports drink column in grocery stores. Whey is one of the proteins present in milk.

Also, whey powder is low fat and low carb, some comes in vanilla flavor, which maybe good for making sweets/dessert. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Most whey powder is fairly heavily sweetened, so you'd need to make adjustments elsewhere in the recipe. Vanilla would be the most suitable flavour by far, but you'd need to adjust for that too. The pure unsweetened/unflavoured stuff is more specialised and harder to obtain.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by heavily sweetened, as far as the brands I came across, they are about 1-6g of sugar per 100g.

Comment: "sweetened" not "sugar-filled", i.e. sweet-tasting, but done with artificial sweetener.   Adding that to an already (sugar-)sweet product  will make for a very sweet result indeed